# Como puedo quitar el hash de la url en angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy en un proyecto que usa mvc 4 y angular.

Tengo un problema con angular:

Estoy en la pantalla de login y luego de loguearme quiero utilizar `$location.url('/Home/Index');` para redireccionar
 a la pagina principal del sistema pero no me funciona.

En el navegador me manda a esta ruta: `http://localhost:9771/#/Home/Index`

Cuando la correcta deberia ser `http://localhost:9771/Home/Index`

Entonces no entiendo de que manera deberia usar `$location`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución depende de como hayas configurado tu aplicación y tu servidor.

**Modo HTML5**

Esta solución asume que estás construyendo un [SPA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Esto significa que para cualquier ruta principal de tu aplicación en el server(no un fragmento de vista en particular) vas a enviar lo mismo que envias cuando te solicitan `/Home/Index` y en esa página tienes todos tus scripts y los scripts de angular cargados. Además de eso estas usando el módulo [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) o [ui-router](http://ui-router.github.io/)

Ej, siempre envías esto

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/rutas.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Tienes que habilitar en modo HTM5 en [$locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider). En un `config` de tu aplicación escribes algo como esto (usualmente cuando defines tus rutas en el cliente)

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .config(function($locationProvider) {
        // Habilitar modo html5
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

Esto efectivamente usa el [API de historial](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/History) del navegador en lugar de refrescar la página completa por lo que sólo tienes que enviar datos y fragmentos para construir tu aplicación. Esto elimina el hash(**#**) o hashbang(**#!**), en caso que lo hayas configurado así, y actualiza las urls como si las estuvieras solicitando directamente al servidor.

**Location**

Esta solución es para cuando **NO** estas construyendo un SPA y tu servidor te manda páginas diferentes en cada petición donde incluyes angular solamente como manipulador del DOM y no para definir tu sistema de rutas.

Ej:

`/Home/Index` te envía una página `<html>` completa con un controller `IndexController`

`/Home/About` te envía una página `<html>` completa con un controller `AboutController`

Esta solución requiere desechar el uso de `$location` y usar en su lugar algo como

```
$window.location.href = '/Home/Index';
```

Esto efectivamente eliminará el hash o hashbang pues angular sólo hace una recarga completa de la página cuando

- Encuentra vínculos que tienen un atributo `target`

  ```
  <a href="/Home/Index" target="_self">vinculo</a>
  ```
- Encuentra vínculos absolutos que van hacia otro dominio

  ```
  <a href="http://otrapagina.com/">vinculo</a>
  ```
- Encuentra vínculos que comienzan con `/` y dirigen a una base diferente de la declarada en el documento

  ```
  <base href="/app"> 
  <a href="/otraapp/Home/Index">vinculo</a>
  ```
- Se modifica la url directamente usando el API de javascript nativo ([`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/location))